# How do I stream computer audio only with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this script: http://www.thegameengine.org/miscellaneous/streaming-twitch-tv-ubuntu/ to stream to Twitch. It works but I don't want to stream my microphone, only the computer audio. How should I change the script to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Choosing computer audio

### PulseAudio

This can be done with PulseAudio and `pavucontrol`. From [HOWTO: Proper Screencasting on Linux](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8746719#post8746719):

> Install `pavucontrol`. Start recording with `ffmpeg`. Start
>   `pavucontrol`. Go to the “Recording” tab and you’ll find `ffmpeg`
>   listed there. Change audio capture from “Internal Audio Analog Stereo”
>   to “Monitor of Internal Audio Analog Stereo“. Now it should record
>   system and application audio instead of microphone.
>
> This setting will be remembered. The next time you want to capture
>   with `ffmpeg`, it will automatically start recording system audio. If
>   you want to revert this, use `pavucontrol` again to change back to
>   microphone input.

### ALSA

Alternatively, ALSA can capture system audio if your audio system supports a loopback device often labeled: *Stereo Mix*, *Wave out mix*, *Mono Mix*, or *What U Hear*. Check in `alsamixer` to see if you have one of these, but [hardware loopback is not as common these days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_card#Crippling_of_features). Then refer to [FFmpeg Wiki: Capturing Audio with ALSA](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA) for the proper syntax if your system supports this feature.

Otherwise I believe you can make a software loopback with ALSA, but I may be incorrect and have no experience with that.

---

## Crappy script

The `ffmpeg` command in that awful, re-occurring script has some issues:

- `-preset` should be used instead of `-vpre`
- `-qscale` is ignored by libx264 (use `-crf` or `-b:v`)
- The group of pictures is not set (use `-g`)
- VBV should be used (use `-maxrate` and `-bufsize`)
- The output may not use a compatible chroma subsampling scheme (use `-pix_fmt yuv420p`)
- x11grab input should use `-framerate`, not `-r`
- `-threads 6` seems like an arbitrary number, and not everyone uses the same hardware. You should either use the default (by removing `-threads`, but it's "greedy"), or set an appropriate value that allows you to encode at a satisfactory rate and yet still allow enough juice to perform the other stuff that you're recording.

The command should be something like this instead:

```
ffmpeg \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i "$INAUD" \
-f x11grab -video_size "$INRES" -framerate "$FPS" -i :0.0 \
-vcodec libx264 -s "$OUTRES" -preset "$QUAL" -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 2000k -g 50 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k \
-f flv "$STREAM_URL"
```

**Note:** Do not just blindly use my example values for `-maxrate`, `-bufsize`, `-g`, and `-b:a`. You must adjust these according to your needs as described in [Encoding for Streaming Sites with FFmpeg](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites). Also see [FFmpeg H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: I installed the control for PulseAudio and got it working by that!